# Apache/2.4.7 on Ubuntu is hanging with no obvious cause, how can I troubleshoot it?

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu.  It's a pretty standard installation using Digital Ocean's one click WordPress install.

It ran fine for months with absolutely no problem.  The problem first appeared 3 days ago and at that time the server had been up for 60 days without a hiccup.

Apache is not crashing but it's just hanging. It won't respond at all. Http requests time out.  The apache2 process is running however.

Top shows no load.  Neither physical nor virtual memory has run out.  There is nothing in the error log.  There is nothing strange in the access log.

The only way to fix it is to reboot the server.  `service apache2 restart` fails, `service apache2 start` fails.

Absolutely *nothing* has been changed on the server at all in many months.  I setup the server around Feb '15.  There have been exactly zero crashes (or hangs) since I setup the server in Feb '15 until 3 days ago.  Since then apache has hung just about once every 24 hours.  I have found no fix other than to reboot the whole system.

When I try to check out the server status (or any other URL really) I get this:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

And it will just hang indefinitely.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot and fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd start by checking disk space, if everything else seems fine. And then run apache in foreground (not using service, but direct command.check  -D option in man page) and also use alternative configuration file with very basic config. directives (in order to check if its issue with Apache itself or other config issues)

Comment: What does `apachctl status` say? It can happen that workers are kept busy (status W), either by connections, or even inexplicably...

Comment: I think you meant "apachectl status", it doesn't say anything, it just hangs indefinitely.  Disk space is not an issue, there is plenty.

Comment: maybe strace -p <pid> would give some hints

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. The list of IPs below (and possibly others) have been hitting /xmlrpc.php (WordPress) over and over over with post requests which eventually caused the server to hang.  I am not sure if this is DDOS or an attempt at brute forcing the WordPress somehow.

179.43.159.26
185.62.189.129
31.49.106.155
37.114.148.184
94.228.215.87
104.255.67.211